# Mocking up an Interface as more than one types

Tags: c#, moq, xunit.net

Why this code doesn't work?

```
var channelsList = new List<IChannel>
{
    Mock.Of<IChannel>(m => m == new ChannelOne()),
    Mock.Of<IChannel>(m => m == new ChannelTwo()),
};
```

Comment: Because that is not how it is suppose to be used. Reference  [LINQ to Mocks](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#linq-to-mocks).  What are you actually trying to achieve?This might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I'm trying to decorate DI `IEnumerable<IChannel>`

Comment: @anatol Could you share `IChannel` interface, and what mean different imlementation which method should be different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `IChannel` is defined as:

```
public interface IChannel
{
    int DoWork();
    int DoOtherWork();
}
```

Then you could define different behavior using `Moq.Linq` like this:

```
var channelsList = new List<IChannel>
{
    Mock.Of<IChannel>(m => m.DoWork() == 1 && m.DoOtherWork() == 1),
    Mock.Of<IChannel>(m => m.DoWork() == 2)
};

Assert.Equal(1, channelsList.First().DoWork());
Assert.Equal(2, channelsList.Last().DoWork());
```

There is however limitation that you cannot setup `Throws` for example...

---

> LINQ to Mocks is great for quickly stubbing out dependencies **that typically don't need further verification**. If you do need to verify later some invocation on those mocks, you can easily retrieve them with `Mock.Get(instance)`.

note:***emphasis mine***

[LINQ to Mocks](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#linq-to-mocks).

Comment: @anatol no worries. happens to all of us. That is why we have SO to reference when we forget. Happy coding.